# Pycharm run the virtual environment with wrong python version

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm, virtualenv

[image]

I moved to a new PC then cloned my project, already set interpreter but terminal keeps using an old version of Python which is the default on my Mac. How can I run newer (venv) Python version in the terminal?

Update image: Using virtualenv in the terminal (not built-in by PyCharm)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@vicktor9450 I will outline steps required to ensure that when you type `python` in your terminal it starts the shell with `python3`

- Creating virtual environment simplest format, **virtualenv [name] --python=[python to use]**
- [ ] Create a virtual environment: `virtualenv venv --python=python3`
- [ ] Goto Pycharm > Preferences > Project > Project Interpreter
- [ ] On the far right of the **Projet Interpreter** dropdown click on the cog/gear icon

[image]
 - [ ] Click on the option **add**

[image]

- [ ] Select existing environment option and select the virtual environment you just created, apply and save changes and that should be all
  [image]

Comment: I didnt install Virtualenvironment in system (macOS), Just use the built in venv in pycharm. Try to created project with built in venv by pycharm and the same bad result. I'll try to install VENV in system (macOS) and update ...